# input:focus only working once

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus, border

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/sZaxc/22/)

I want my textbox to have a `#96f226` border at `input:focus`, and it works. But if you click away and click back in, it doesn't have that green border anymore.

CSS:

```
#input {
  background: #4a4a4a;
  border: 1px solid #454545;
  color: #96f226;
}
#input:hover {
  background: #656565;
}
#input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #96f226
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='input'>
```

## Edit:

---

It only doesn't do it if you click in, start typing, click out, and *then* click in.

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome

Comment: I'm using chrome too. It still doesn't

Comment: I setup a jsfiddle and it works for me.. does this jsfiddle work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/3WxKK/

Comment: That fiddle works fine for me in Firefox. *edit* both fiddles. *edit* and in Chrome too.

Comment: Did you read my edit?

Comment: Saw your edit and tried to reproduce but it still works with your steps.  What version of Chrome are you on?  What OS as well?

Comment: I am on OSX 10.7.5 and Chrome 30.0.1599.101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because your jQuery is adding an inline-style to the input in line 9:

```
 $('#input').css('border', '1px solid #454545');
```

Inline-styles override styles defined within the stylesheet.

A quick fix would be to add `!important` to your CSS:

```
#input:focus {
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #96f226 !important;
}
```

That works, but it's more of a hack.

If I understand correctly, you're adding the inline-style to remove the red border after an error. A better way to do this would be to simply remove the inline-style. That would sort out the conflict and you wouldn't need to add the `!important` hack. Replace line 9 in your jQuery with the following:

```
$('#input').css('border', '');
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice that my jquery styling was getting in the way.